# Chrome Debugging Protocol: Create local storage value

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, protocols

I am using the library `chrome-remote-interface` to try and add a localStorage value to chrome after a page change like so:

```
    CDP( ( client ) => {
    // extract domains
    const { DOM, DOMStorage, Page } = client
    Page.navigate( { url } )
        .then( () => {
            const storageId = {
                securityOrigin: 'https://my.jive.com',
                isLocalStorage: true
            }

            return DOMStorage.setDOMStorageItem( storageId, 'key', 'value' )
        .then( Page.reload.bind( Page ) )
```

but when I run this I get the following error

```
 { Error: Invalid parameters (storageId: object expected; key: string value expected; value: string value expected)
```

I am not sure why it's acting like I havent passed in any of the arguments correctly? Also if any one can help me out with Chrome Debugger Protocol docs, they seem to have a lot of references to ids and they give no indication as to how to obtain these ids https://paulirish.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/DOMStorage/ anyone know where to look?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
DOMStorage.setDOMStorageItem({ storageId: 'id', key: 'key', value: 'value' });
```